# How to zip all downloaded files in the browser in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5, jszip

I found [this article](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/15/give-the-power-of-zip-to-your-sapui5-applications/comment-page-1/#comment-564720) which properly explains a working way (I tested it) of how to create a zip file of a "Hello.txt" file that the author creates with the function:

```js
onPress: function(oControlEvent) {
   var zip = new JSZip();
   zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n"); //Here creates the file and the context
   zip.generateAsync({
      type: "blob"
   })
   .then(function(content) {
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
   });
},
```

I have the following function which successfully opens a new window and downloads all selected files:

```js
downloadAttachments:function(){
  this.byId("UploadCollection").getSelectedItems().map(object => window.open(object.mProperties.url));
},
```

How can I make the zip file contain all the downloads instead of the "Hello.txt" file?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is not possible to zip the files in SAPUI5. The reason is that the JSUtils library doesn't work as expected in SAPUI5. I believe that the main reason for this is that it is Promise based.

Note: Promises doesn't work on an oData service in SAPUI5 because it only accepts batch calls or async.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your files and call `zip.file(...)` for all of them.

```js
var files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"];
var zip = new JSZip();

files.forEach((file) => {
    zip.file(file, "some content based on what you want to add");
});

zip.generateAsync({
    type: "blob"
}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

You can read more of the JSZip documentation [here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html). In your case you can iterate the selected items and extract whatever you need from them to be included in the zip.